# How can I achieve this layout with a UITabBarController

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am building a UITabBarController programmatically and have a requirement to align my tab bar icons / text in the following fashion.

Is this possible? I am unsure what properties I should be looking to change?

[image]

Comment: Sorry no, I've simple copied and pasted quickly, these will be 3 different icons / titles. What I am struggling with is how to align the title and image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try moving title and image of your `UITabBarItem`

Start with moving the whole *Title* to left and up

[image]

then move *Image* to right and down

[image]

---

[image]

... note that this works with custom image, not with *System item*

---

Now you can be more lazy and create custom subclass of `UITabBar`

```
class CustomTabBar: UITabBar {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        items?.forEach {
            $0.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: -20, vertical: -20)
            $0.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 3, left: 30, bottom: -3, right: -30)
        }
    }
}
```